# Understanding Azure Media Service Encoding permutations - that increases file size

Tags: azure, video, encoding, azure-media-services

How system can improve a video quality automatically? For example, a dark line on my face in video can't be removed by system automatically...make sense. Here I'm trying to understand Azure Media Services encoding permutations.

When I uploaded a 55.5 MB mp4 file and encoded with "H264AdaptiveBitrateMP4Set720p" encoder preset, I received following output files:

[image]
Now look at green rectangular highlighted video file, this looks good according to input file size. But if you look at red rectangular highlighted video files, these are improved files for adaptive streaming, which looks useless if you compare with my example 'a dark line on my face'. Here's my questions and I would love to read your input on this:

1. What are exact reasons encoder increases the file size?
2. Why I should pay more for bandwidth and storage on these large files, how I convince clients?
3. Is there any way I can define not to create such files when scheduling encoding?

Any input is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1) The dark lines appearing on your face have nothing to do with encoding. Encoding simply means re-arranging bits that make up the video using a different compression algorithm than the one used in the source video.

2) As you see from the filenames of the files generated, they all have a different bitrate, denoted in kbps. This is the amount of data, i.e. number of bits, that the transcoder has to decode to get 1-second worth of video footage. The higher the bit-rate, the better is the quality of the video because there is more detail such as better light and color information stored in every pixel and hence in every frame of such a video.

As a corollary, a higher-bit rate video is suited better for faster internet connections.

So, Azure must have converted from your source video, these 4 different videos of different bit-rates, all having the same video (h.264) and audio (AAC) encoding.

3) As to how to let Azure not make so many files, I do not know the answer to that. I am pretty sure it will be some configuration somewhere but I honestly have no idea. I am confident, though, that it is only a matter of some configuration to tell it to stop doing the other bit-rate conversions.

In summary:

a) to clear off the dark thingy on your face in the video, you have to edit the source video in a video editor and that has nothing to do with video encoding.

b) The file sizes are different due to different bit-rates, meaning differences in light and color information, i.e. shadow detail, stored in every pixel of every frame of the video footage.

Those users who have a faster Internet connection, to them you could show the option of downloading a higher-bit-rate file. The higher bit-rate file will show slightly better quality even under the same video resolution, i.e. 720p in your case.

Comment: Dear Water Cooler v2 (Interesting name!)
I really appreciate your help here. 

I understand your point about the bitrate.The question that I have is that if my video has an innate bitrare of 1000KBPS, how is Azure adding 2000 additional KBPS to the bitrate?
As you are suggesting, it certainly wouldn't improve the quality of the video as the original captured bitrate was determined by a certain standard of equipment quality (camera, light etc.). 
1. What data is Azure adding, while increasing my original bitrate?
2. Is it really necessary, considering it costs us extra bandwidth to deliver this

Comment: Another, if encoding happens based on some sort of encoding rules this looks like hardcoded on Azure Media Services. I see possibility of writing own encoding presets, like when i start upload i will first check the video quality and based on that i will pass presets. If we can do this, then why this is not part of Azure Media Services default. Lots of questions in my mind on this, because no client will accept higher size, we can't convince.. you geeting my point?

Comment: A complete answer to your question will not be possible without writing a 1500-word essay on this topic as I learnt all this over a period of 4 years of regular video shooting and editing practice coupled with reading about every day.

There is far too much you need to know to make an intelligent decision about this independently, such as color spaces, compression algorithms, camera bit-rates, alpha-blending, raster operation, video and audio codes, object tracking, edge detection, etc.

Comment: I can offer you a suggestion:

1) Sample 2 or 3 videos you made before uploading them. See how they look. Are they of an acceptable quality?

2) Upload them

3) Download each file with a different bitrate for that video. Watch it. Which is the lowest bitrate that is acceptable to you in terms of video quality?

4) Keep that. Is that bitrate good enough for your target audience's internet connection speed? If it is, choose this bitrate, if not, go to the next higher bitrate and repeat step 4 until you are satisfied.

5) Stick to that bitrate as a principal and remove all other files.

Comment: So, the other files are not necessary if cost matters a lot to you.

However, if you are still curious, I can tell you that in a nut shell, the encoder does one of two things to create files with higher bitrates:

1) Pixel interpolation -- creating more pixels out of a few number of pixels per frame even while keeping the resolution constant.

OR

2) Something akin to a widening conversion you must know of in .NET. If you had to pad an integer value into a long, the CLR would be able to do it by padding its significant bits (on the left) with zeros.

Comment: So, if there is no real data that can be added to improve the original image, the encoder widens the data while keeping the same amount of information. This is in extremely rare cases, though.

Comment: Also, a higher bit rate does improve the video quality in most cases. This is because the source file that the encoder uses to create other files of higher bitrates is highly compressed and has a lot of information that can be "blown out" to create a better image per frame.

Comment: However, depending on how you shot the original video, this may or may not make a practically visible difference in your video quality. This is something you'll have to check by watching the videos with different bitrates. A cinematographer, on the other hand, will have no problem creating a highly compressed video that can be made significantly better at higher bitrates.